# NativeScript side drawer not able to load router-outlet

Tags: angular2-routing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have created the side menu using the `RadSideDrawer` directive in nativescript and when I try to load child routes in it, except the default load, all subsequent loads show me a blank screen.

This is how I am loading the content.

```
<ScrollView tkMainContent class="menu-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ScrollView>
```

Navigation Logic:

```
<StackLayout>

        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" [nsRouterLink]="['./']" class="menu-item" 
                [nsRouterLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" nsRouterLinkActive="active" horizontalAlignment="left">
             <Label text="{{inspectionsIcon}}" class="icon" ></Label>   
             <Label text="Reports"></Label>   
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" [nsRouterLink]="['properties']"  class="menu-item" nsRouterLinkActive="active" horizontalAlignment="left">
            <Label text="{{propertiesIcon}}"  class="icon" ></Label>
             <Label text="Properties" ></Label>   
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" [nsRouterLink]="['settings']" class="menu-item" nsRouterLinkActive="active" horizontalAlignment="left">
            <Label text="{{settingsIcon}}"  class="icon" ></Label>
             <Label text="Settings"></Label>   
        </StackLayout>



    </StackLayout>
```

So when the parent route loads I see the content of the default child. When I switch to any other child routes I see a blank screen. Any help in fixing this would be appreciated.

I know that the navigation logic is fine cause it loads fine when i just comment out the `RadSideDrawer` and use it as a list view

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and its due to a circular reference when the RadSideDrawer is in the same component template as the default home router path, in your case `[nsRouterLink]="['./']`

In my case, when I added console.log to the constructor of my HomeComponent which contained my RadSideDrawer, i saw the constructor fired twice as well as a label which I had inside:

`<ScrollView tkMainContent class="menu-content"`>

Solution (suggested to me by Telerik) is to have the default route point to another "landing page" like [nsRouterLink]="['welcomPage'] and thereby removing the circular reference.

Comment: I added some breakpoints in my root component which loads the RadSideDrawer and the controller is loading only once, can you direct me to some code samples that I can refer to?

Comment: aha - have a look at this example: https://github.com/greenstevester/nativescript-sidedrawer-example